# self hosted linux agent: package.json not in _work directory: npm ERR! enoent ENOENT for package.json

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am running a local CentOs server. On that I have succesfully created a [self hosted Linux agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/linux-agent?view=azure-devops).

Also had to install git, node and npm on that system and the first runs just echoing a command were successful.

Now I would like to build an Angular application with it using a pipeline.

I've started out with a blank boilerplate Angular project via nx.

In the project root, there are the nx/angular files and also a `package.json`.

```
./client/
./client/package.json
./client/apps
./client/libs
./client/node_modules
./client/tsconfig.base.json
./client/azure/azure-pipelines.yml # the pipeline file is here
./client/etc...
```

I've started out with this `azure-pipelines.yml` file:

```yaml
trigger:
  - main

pool:
  name: some-pool
  demands:
    - Agent.Name -equals some-vm0

steps:
  - script: npm i
    displayName: npm install
```

In the pipeline job I get the following output:

```bash
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/username/myagent/_work/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/username/myagent/_work/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

So it looks like it cannot find the file `package.json` in the correct location.

How does it work exactly?

The first step in the pipeline is a "Starting: Checkout Repository Name@main to s" and shows that it's "Receiving objects". I guess that would contain the package.json file. Where are those files stored on the agents machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is a set of [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) that you can use.

Did a bunch of them and eventually found out you can use:

```
  - script: |
      ls -la $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s
    displayName: List Contents of Build Directory/s
  - script: |
      ls -la $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    displayName: List Contents of Build.SourcesDirectory
  - script: |
      ls -la $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
    displayName: List Contents of System.DefaultWorkingDirectory
```

To get the location where the files of the repository are copied to.

Since traversing is not ideal (`../client`) we can use the sourcesdirectory and client folder together:

```
trigger:
  - main

pool:
  name: some-pool
  demands:
    - Agent.Name -equals some-vm0

variables:
  ClientRootFolder: 'client' # add a variable which you can re-use

steps:
  - script: npm i
    displayName: npm install
    workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/$(ClientRootFolder)
```